# What is the right way to reload express middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple express app. But I want to reload middleware on e.g. some event.
Here is the code that works fine (middleware now uses new config) but I want to know if this is the right way to do it:

```
var express = require('express');
var myMiddleware = require('./myMiddleware.js');
var app = express();

app.use(myMiddleware({ option1: '1', option2: '2' }));

app.listen(3000);

.
.
.
// then on some event I call it again with other options

app.use(myMiddleware({ option1: '100', option2: '200' }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supported Express API to uninstall a previous installed middleware function so you can then reinstall it.

To do so, you would have to hack Express in order to remove that middleware from it's internal routing array.

An alternate implementation would be to proxy the middleware so you can then control what is actually called.

```
// initial value of middleware
let currentMiddleware = myMiddleware{ option1: '1', option2: '2' });
// my middleware proxy

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // call currently indicated middleware function
    currentMiddleware(req, res, next);
});
```

Then, on some future event:

```
// change middleware that is called via currentMiddleware
// this new middleware  will be used on all future requests
currentMiddlware = myMiddleware({ option1: '100', option2: '200' });
```

---

Keep in mind that this is a global change on the server for ALL future requests from all users.  Thus, it's a pretty unusual thing to change the configuration of a live server for all users.

If you really just want a change to affect future requests from one user, then that would need a completely different implementation.  You could still use the proxy design mentioned above, but you would use branching logic to decide (probably based on some state in a user session variable) which middleware to execute for each given request.